# How to display submenus in customized Joomla menu?

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu-item, submenu

I want add schema in my Joomla menu.

My code:

```
$menu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu();
// Get menu items - array with menu items
$items = $menu->getItems('menutype', 'mainmenu');
//print_r($items);
?>
<ul itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
    <?php foreach($items as $i => $menu_item){ ?>
        <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.10leaves.ae/"><?php if($menu_item->level == '1') { echo $menu_item->title; } ?></a>
            <?php if($menu_item->level == '2') { ?>
            <ul>
                <li><?php echo $menu_item->title; ?></li>
            </ul>
            <?php } ?>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

The problem is, the sub-menu is not being displayed.

For Example :

```
<ul itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
    <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.10leaves.ae/">Home</a></li>
    <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.10leaves.ae/">DIFC</a></li>
    <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.10leaves.ae/">ADGM</a></li>
    <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.10leaves.ae/">About</a></li>
    <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.10leaves.ae/">Publications</a></li>
    <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.10leaves.ae/">FinTech: Now Everybody Wants A Slice of the Pie</a></li>
    <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.10leaves.ae/">The Role of Financial Centres in Emerging Economies</a></li>
    <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.10leaves.ae/">Bitcoin versus Ethereum </a></li>
    <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.10leaves.ae/">ADGM</a></li>
    <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.10leaves.ae/">DIFC</a></li>
    <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.10leaves.ae/">Finance</a></li>
    <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.10leaves.ae/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

The `Publications` menu has submenus `FinTech` and two more.

I cannot figure out how to print the submenus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the parent menu precedes it child menus, I think it is most sensible to batch the submenus and then just before a new 
`level = 1` item occurs, you unload the batch of submenus in your desired structure.

I should declare that I am new to Joomla and I do not know if there is a native Joomla way to perform this task.  Also, I don't personally like bouncing in and out of php because I think it increases the chances of developer error, so I'll write this up as one continuous php block.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/EcMsc))

```
echo '<ul itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">';
    foreach ($items as $i => $menu_item) {
        if($menu_item->level == '1') {
            if ($i) {             // not the first iteration ($i is not 0)
                if ($sub_menu) {  // only display a batch of submenus if batch is not empty
                    echo '<ul><li>' , implode('</li><li>', $sub_menu) , '</li></ul>';
                }
                echo '</li>';
            }
            $sub_menu = array();  // start over with a new empty batch
            echo '<li itemprop="name">';
                echo '<a itemprop="url" href="http://www.10leaves.ae/">' , $menu_item->title , '</a>';
        } elseif ($menu_item->level == '2') {
            $sub_menu[] = $menu_item->title;  // add to the batch
        }
    }
    if ($items) {
        echo '</li>';             // close final listitem tag
    }
echo '</ul>';                     // close first unorderedlist tag
```

Output:

```
<ul itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
    <li itemprop="name">
        <a itemprop="url" href="http://www.10leaves.ae/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li itemprop="name">
        <a itemprop="url" href="http://www.10leaves.ae/">DIFC</a>
    </li>
    <li itemprop="name">
        <a itemprop="url" href="http://www.10leaves.ae/">ADGM</a>
    </li>
    <li itemprop="name">
        <a itemprop="url" href="http://www.10leaves.ae/">About</a>
    </li>
    <li itemprop="name">
        <a itemprop="url" href="http://www.10leaves.ae/">Publications</a>
        <ul>
            <li>FinTech: Now Everybody Wants A Slice of the Pie</li>
            <li>The Role of Financial Centres in Emerging Economies</li>
            <li>Bitcoin versus Ethereum </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li itemprop="name">
        <a itemprop="url" href="http://www.10leaves.ae/">ADGM</a>
    </li>
    <li itemprop="name">
        <a itemprop="url" href="http://www.10leaves.ae/">DIFC</a>
    </li>
    <li itemprop="name">
        <a itemprop="url" href="http://www.10leaves.ae/">Finance</a>
    </li>
    <li itemprop="name">
        <a itemprop="url" href="http://www.10leaves.ae/">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```